# Appium multiple clicks no longer working

Tags: python, click, appium, double-click

I updated appium to version 1.3.6 today and the portion of my tests where multiple clicks are used are no longer working. I basically have an element that I want to click three times, like I would a double-click.

This is the code that was working prior to the update:

```
some_element = self.driver.find_element_by_name('some_element')
some_element.click()
some_element.click()
some_element.click()
```

In attempts to figure out why this no longer works, I embedded print commands between the clicks and noticed that the three clicks aren't happening fast enough to be registered by the application.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, instead of click use tap:

https://github.com/appium/python-client#tap

The wrong way:

```
some_element = self.driver.find_element_by_name('some_element')
some_element.click()
some_element.click()
some_element.click()
```

The right way:

(from appium.webdriver.common.touch_action import TouchAction)

```
some_element = self.driver.find_element_by_name('some_element')
triple_click = TouchAction(self.driver)
# the parameters for tap are element, x-offset, y-offset, and count
triple_click.tap(some_element, 0, 0, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put sleep command in between each click. I am sure this will fix the issue.

Comment: I attempted putting the sleep commands in-between the clicks and it didn't  fix the problem. The clicks aren't happening fast enough to be registered by the application as a triple-click